# Do I have to pay for uPlay?

Tags: ps3, ubisoft-connect

I found [this](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15731/~/how-do-i-activate-uplay-passport?) guide whilst researching my [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/80394/16142) question. As well as this other question about [What is Uplay? Can I play Ubisoft games without it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32419/what-is-uplay-can-i-play-ubisoft-games-without-it)

I'm a bit confused.

Do I have to pay for it/the passport if a game has it?

Comment: uPlay itself is free; are you talking about an online pass deal or something?  For PC, it's part of the game price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in an answer to one of the question you linked to in you question, UPlay is UbiSoft's cross game mini-social network for its games. It includes a point and reward system which allows you to unlock content in games by spending points gained through playing supported games, for example, you may gain 10 points by playing Assassin's Creed II and spend them on a reward in Prince of Persia.

UPlay passport, on the other hand,  is a piece of downloable content used in recent UbiSoft games and is required for accessing online portions of the games. It's is similar to the PSN Pass in games like Resistance 3 and Racthet & Clank All 4 One and the Online Pass in EA games like Battlefield 3. New copies of UbiSoft games include a code to redeem for a free UPlay Passport, but if you buy a used copy where the code was already redeemed by another player, you'll need to pay for a new code, usually about $10.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right, yes you do have to pay for UPlay (it's $9.99).

Comment: The part of UPlay you have to pay for is the **UPlay passport**, and that's only if you bought the game second hand and the code that came with it was already redeemed